# reshaping tensors for multi head attention in pytorch - view vs transpose

Tags: arrays, optimization, pytorch, tensor, attention-model

I'm learning about the attention operator in the deep learning domain. I understand that to compute multi head attention efficiently in parallel, the input tensors (*query*, *key*, *value*) have to be reshaped properly.
Assuming *query*, *key* and *value* are three tensor of identical shape `[N, L, D]`, in which

- *N* is the batch size
- *L* is the sequence length
- *D* is the hidden/embedding size,

they should be turned into `[N*N_H, L, D_H]` tensors, where *N_H* is the number of heads for the attention layer and *D_H* is the embedding size of each head.

The [pytorch code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/functional.py#L5114) seems to do exactly that. Here below I post the code for reshaping the query tensor (key, value are equally deemed)

```
q = q.contiguous().view(tgt_len, bsz * num_heads, head_dim).transpose(0, 1)
```

I don't get why they perform both a `view` and a `transpose` call, when the result would be the same by just doing

```
q = q.contiguous().view(bsz * num_heads, tgt_len, head_dim)
```

Other than avoiding an additional function call, using `view` alone also guarantees that the resulting tensor is still contiguous in memory, whereas this doesn't hold (to the best of my knowledge) for `transpose`. I suppose working with contiguous data is beneficial whenever possible to make computations potentially faster (may lead to fewer memory accesses, better exploiting of spatial locality of data, etc.).

What's the use case for having a `transpose` call after a `view`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results AREN'T necessarily the same:

```
a = torch.arange(0, 2 * 3 * 4)
b = a.view(2, 3, 4).transpose(1, 0)
#tensor([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
     [12, 13, 14, 15]],

    [[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
     [16, 17, 18, 19]],

    [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
     [20, 21, 22, 23]]])

c = a.view(3, 2, 4)
#tensor([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
     [ 4,  5,  6,  7]],

    [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
     [12, 13, 14, 15]],

    [[16, 17, 18, 19],
     [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```